# Expect, sed, and Variable Substitution

Tags: bash, sed, expect

I'm calling an `expect` script from a bash script and passing an argument to be used for `sed` string replacement.

But it errors out b/c of the variable in `sed` statement. Any suggestions on how to fix this? I've tried escape `\/` but no much success.

The parameter is passed successfully (cde)

The code:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
# ./sshlogin.exp uptime
set hosts {myhost.com}
set user root
set password xxxx
set mount [lindex $argv 0]
foreach vm $hosts {
    set timeout -1
    # now ssh
    spawn ssh $user@$vm -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no
    match_max 100000 # Look for passwod prompt
    expect "*?assword:*"
    # Send password aka $password
    send -- "$password\r"
    # send blank line (\r) to make sure we get back to gui
    expect "]# "
    send "sed -e -i 's/abc/${mount}/g' /my/files.new\r"
    expect "]# "
    sleep 1
    send -- "exit\r"
expect eof }
```

Error:

```
# sed -e 's/abc/cde
> /g' /my/files.new
sed: -e expression #1, char 37: unterminated `s' command
```

Comment: @heemayl thank you for the comment. I'm getting the following error: `# sed -e -i 's#abc#cde
> #g' /my/files.new
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `-'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### What's Broken

The following is an invalid invocation:

```
sed -e -i 's/abc/${mount}/g'
```

It is invalid because:

1. The quoted expression is not associated with the `-e` flag.
2. `${mount}` may contain a newline or leading/trailing whitespace characters.

### How to Fix It

In order to fix your problems, you should:

1. Switch your command line arguments.
2. Ensure that the `-i` flag is provided an argument (e.g. an empty string) so that it will work with a non-GNU sed.
3. Strip any newlines or leading/trailing whitespace from your *mount* variable with `string trim`.

For example:

```
set mount [string trim [lindex $argv 0]]
# ...
send "sed -i'' -e 's/abc/${mount}/g' /my/files.new\r"
```

Comment: @CodeGenome thank you for your answer, but I get the following error:
`# sed -i'' -e 's/abc/cde
> #' /my/files.new
sed: -e expression #1, char 37: unterminated `s' command`

Comment: @CodeGenome the value of `${mount}` at runtime is correct, since the error shows it" `cde`